# Should I implement IDisposable for a class containing a Thread

Tags: c#, multithreading, idisposable

I have a class that uses the [Thread](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) class:

```
class A
{
    public Thread thread
    { get; set; }
}
```

Should I implement IDisposable and set Thread property to null?

```
class A : IDisposable
{
    public Thread Thread
    { get; set; }

    protected bool Disposed
    { get; set; }


    public void Dispose()
    {
        Dispose(true);
        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }

    protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (!this.Disposed)
        {
            if (disposing)
            {
                if (Thread != null)
                    Thread = null;
            }

            Disposed = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Or not?
Why?

Comment: Dispose is mostly for unmanaged resources.  In your case, when your class goes out of scope, your `Thread` object will eventually be garbage collected anyway.

Comment: Often Dispose is used too free memory faster...

Comment: @rekire Nope, it's not, and it doesn't have that effect even if you tried.  (At least if you're referring to managed memory.)

Comment: @rekire That's not entirely correct. Or at least the situation is far more complicated then that.

Comment: @rekire: Not in this case.  The `Thread` object is made available for garbage collection at about the same time, whether Dispose is used or not.

Comment: So it doesn't make sense to dispose and null private stuff? (I jused that mostly on file or network streams)

Comment: @rekire: Not unless it's an unmanaged resource.  File and network streams implement `IDisposable`, so you can just wrap them in `using` statements.

Comment: @jgauffin Thread does not have Dispose method.

Comment: @rekire It doesn't makes sense to use `Dispose` just to set something to null.  It *does* make sense to implement `IDisposable` to call `Dispose` on an instance field that is also `IDisposable`.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Although a `using` statement only applies if the resource is used just in the scope of a single method; if it's stored as an instance field then you can't do that, and you need the containing object to also implement `IDisposable`.  If `Thread` actually implemented `IDisposable` (it doesn't) then so would this class.

Comment: @Servy: You can still use `using` on a member variable.  Dispose still gets called when the `using` statement goes out of scope.

Comment: @RobertHarvey You can, technically, but it usually doesn't do what you want it to do.  If you are using the variable across the scope of several methods then it's not *useful* even though it's *possible*.  It would end up disposing of the resource before you were done with it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You implement `IDisposable` only when your class is handling an unmanaged object, resources or other `IDisposable` objects. A Thread is not an unmanaged object and will get garbage collected when nothing is referencing it or when the process handling it is terminated. Since Thread is not implementing `IDisposable`, your class referencing it does not need to implement it either.

Optionally, for `IDisposable` within the scope of a method, they can be wrapped in a `using` statement and the Dispose() method is automatically called when the scope is exited.

Comment: Mostly true, but if `Thread` implemented IDisposable, you could just wrap a `using` statement around it.  No need to re-implement IDisposable in the surrounding class.

Comment: @RobertHarvey The purpose of a thread is to do something asynchronous, so if you wrap your thread in a using statement, and start your thread in it, then your thread would immediately be disposed once the thread is started. Maybe the thread is not finished yet it would be disposed immediately. So I do not think wrapping a thread object around a using statement -even if you could - would be a good idea.

Comment: @Maarten: Why would it get disposed as soon as the thread start? It should only get disposed when exiting the scope of the `using` statement.

Comment: @Marc-AndréJutras: That's right, but if you want to start your thread "fire and forget style," you can't wrap it in a `using` statement (in our contrived hypothetical), because it would get cleaned up right after it is started.

Comment: @Maarten: Which is probably a good reason why `Thread` doesn't implement `IDisposable`. :P

Comment: How exactly would you define "unmanaged resource"?  I would define unmanaged resource as being something which an object has asked some outside entity to do on its behalf, to the detriment of others, which that outside entity will keep doing until told to stop.  Things like files and unmanaged memory blocks fit this pattern (having a file open, for example, often means that one has been granted exclusive access to the file, to the detriment of anyone else wanting to use it; holding a memory block means the memory allocator is blocking anyone else from using it).

Comment: The above sample code is unclear on what the thread is used for, but most objects that create a `Thread` do so for the purpose of having the thread do something on their behalf.  If the thread still exists when nobody still cares about the object that created it, that's a good sign that the thread should be told that it no longer needs to keep running for the benefit of its creator.  The standard way for the thing that creates the thread's owner to let that owner know that nobody cares about it anymore is via `Dispose`.

Comment: @supercat: if nobody care about it, and nobody reference it, it will be garbage collected. It is not an unmanaged resource.

Comment: @Marc-AndréJutras: It is sometimes necessary for object (e.g. `George`) to hold references to things they don't really "care about", so that they can update those objects for the benefit of other objects that do care about them.  For example, `George` may hold a reference to an object (e.g. `Joe`) for the purpose of writing data to `Joe` that other objects might read from it.  If no reference to `Joe` is held by anything that's ever going to read it, there's no point writing data to it, but there's no way the GC can know that.

Comment: @supercat: Yeah... but if no object has any reference toward `Joe`, the GC knows that and will collect it. If no object has a reference toward a Thread, the GC will also collect it. If you want a thread to continue running, you must have a reference toward it.

Comment: @Marc-AndréJutras: Every live managed thread in .net will hold a rooted reference to its corresponding `Thread` object, which code running in that thread can read via the `Thread.CurrentThread` static property.  I am unaware of any means situation where a running thread would cease run merely because no user code is holding a reference to its corresponding `Thread` object.  Are you aware of any?  As for `Joe`, since `George` will be writing data to it, `George` will be holding a reference.  In some cases, that could (and should) be a `WeakReference`, but determining that isn't always easy.

Answer (score 2):

It depends what your thread is doing. If your thread is performing a long running task that may run indefinitely, then I would consider *that* thread as a resource (which will not be garbage collected). For example consider if the thread is designed to poll some state indefinitely, or consume  items from a queue (like a thread-pool thread consumes tasks or a TCP server consumes new connections) etc. In this case, I would say the natural effect of disposing your class would be to free up this thread resource. Setting it to null is not really useful in this case. Rather `Dispose` should probably involve flagging a synchronization event (or maybe a CancellationToken) to notify the thread that it should finish up its infinite task, and then the disposing thread should wait some time for the thread to finish (join). As always with joins, be careful of a deadlock scenario and consider some alternative action if the thread refuses to terminate. For obvious reasons I would *not* do this join in the finalizer.

As an example of what I'm meaning, consider the scenario where your `class A` is actually `class MyTcpListener`, designed to listen and wait for new TCP connections on a given port indefinitely. Then consider what you expect following (somewhat unlikely) code to do:

```
using (MyTcpListener listener = new MyTcpListener(port:1234))
{
    // Do something here
}

// Create another one. This would fail if the previous Dispose
// did not unbind from the port.
using (MyTcpListener listener = new MyTcpListener(port:1234))
{
    // Do something else here
}
```

Assuming I know the constructor of `MyTcpListener` creates a listener thread, I would expect that after the `Dispose` call has returned that the `MyTcpListener` would no longer be bound to the TCP port - i.e. that the TCP listener thread would have fully terminated. It goes without saying that if you didn't provide some mechanism to stop the listener that there would be a resource leak. The stopping mechanism could be a call to some method "Stop", but I personally think the "Dispose" pattern fits this scenario more cleanly since forgetting to stop something does not generally imply a resource leak.

Your code may call for different assumptions, so I would suggest judging it on the scenario. If your thread is short-running, e.g. it has some known finite task to complete and then it will terminate on its own, then I would say that disposing is less critical or perhaps useless.